# While Loop checking for letter within string in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to create a while-loop that loops until a random string has been created that starts with "A" and ends with "Z".

```
import string
from random import choice

def random_string():
    """ Generates a 5 letter random string. """
    rs = ''.join(choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(5))
    print(rs)
    
    

while random_string()[-1] != "Z" and random_string()[0]) != "A":
    print("keep going")
return random_string
```

So far I have this and I am running into trouble with the while loop checking for the first and last letter. Is there a simpler (and correct) way to test this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are calling the function twice, so you are checking two different strings. You could try calling the function once, storing the result in a variable and then checking the variable in the `while` condition.

Comment: The parenthesis around the `while` condition were wrong, and the operator to check logical AND in Python is `and`, not `&`

Comment: If the indentation in your code is the same as the indentation in your question, you hit `return rs` before you ever enter the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as you intended.

```
import string
from random import choice
    
random_string = ''.join(choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(5))

while random_string[-1] != "Z" or random_string[0] != "A":
    random_string = ''.join(choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(5))
    print("keep going")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the first and last letters in your string to be the same, why not just randomize the middle 3 characters.

You would have a successful result every run.

```
pre = 'A'
suf = 'Z'
n = 3

result = pre + ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(n)) + suf

#'ACUUZ'
```

---

Id you want to achieve this with the `while` loop, you need to ensure your `return` is outside of your loop, and that your loop runs whilst your condition is not met.

```
 def random_string():
    rs = ''.join(choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(5))
    while rs[-1] != "Z" or rs[0] != "A":
        rs = ''.join(choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(5))
    return rs
```

With the above, we define our return after the `while` loop, ensure it only returns when a match has been found.

Output

```
for i in range(10): 
    print(random_string())

ASKPZ
AHOKZ
AYWQZ
ASHYZ
ACENZ
ASIVZ
ADTVZ
AZWHZ
AAHHZ
AKZHZ
```

Comment: This makes sense -- though the intention of the original code might be to simulate the random experiment of sampling until you get a hit, in which case this suggestion skips the experiment completely.

Comment: @JohnColeman Agreed, i have also added how to achieve this with the code in question.